# In Javascript find if a checkbox is focused

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

In Javascript how can I tell if a checkbox has focus or not?

I thought there would be a method or property called isfocused. But apparently not.

By in focus I mean they've tabbed to it using the keyboard and at this point pressing space would check the box.

Comment: Why do you need to know if it 'has focus'? Does that mean they've selected the label next to it?  Only 'chec' and uncheck seem to matter.

Comment: In the javascript I'm responding to some keyboard events and I need to know if it's the last checkbox in the list.

Comment: What happens if they use a mouse?

Comment: Then I don't need to worry about it. It comes down to if they tab past the last checkbox in the list, I need to hide the list. If they use the mouse, the list will be closed anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an event handler that is wired to the onfocus event. When it's called, set a global var to remember that it's got the focus. Write another one on the onblur event which clears the variable.

Comment: [This answer is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430561/how-can-i-check-if-my-element-id-has-focus)

Answer (score 1):

There is a onfocus event that fires when an element receives focus.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var isFocused = false;

</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="team" value="team" onfocus="javascript:isFocused = true;">Spurs<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to just hook into the onfocus and onblur events for the checkbox to keep track of when it gets and loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of the basics of an implementation that might help you.  Note: the output stuff is just for demonstration purposes and not part of the actual solution.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    onload = function()
    {
        var f = document.forms.test;
        f.focusedElem = null;
        updateOutput( f );

        for ( var i = 0, l = f.elements.length, elem; i < l; i++ )
        {
            elem = f.elements[i];
            elem.onfocus = function( elem )
            {
                return function()
                {
                    elem.form.focusedElem = elem;
                    updateOutput( elem.form );
                }
            }( elem )

            elem.onblur = function()
            {
                f.focusedElem = null;
                updateOutput( f )
            }
        }
    }

    function updateOutput( f )
    {
        document.getElementById( 'output' ).innerHTML = ( null == f.focusedElem ) ? 'Nothing!' : f.focusedElem.id;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="test">

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo2">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo3">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo4">

</form>

What has focus? <span id="output"></span>

</body>
</html>
```