# How to lock focus in a specific div using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developping some kind of modal popup using jQuery and I have some problems with the focus.

What happens right now, is that when I press the tab key, the focus goes to the controls hidden behind the popup.

Is there a way to force the focus to remain only on the controls in the popup window ?

Comment: You could could put something like `onblur="this.focus()"` inside any controls in the popup, though that would lock focus into whatever's currently selected. A bit more code to determine if whatever's gaining focus should be allowed to gain focus would be needed.

Comment: Thanks, however, this would not work for me because I have to respect the WCAG 2.0 AA guidelines and all controls should be reachable using the keyboard.

Comment: Then you're contradicting yourself. "Do not allows controls to be reached, but all controls must be reachable".

Comment: I want the focus to be contained inside the popup window when the window is opened. When the window is closed, other controls should be accessible using the keyboard.

Comment: So is it an ACTUAL popup, as in a new browser window? OR is it a jQuery modal popup which is still contained in the original page?

Comment: a jQuery modal popup contained in the original page

Comment: @Martin: that's why I said you'd want some extra code to determine what the new element with focus is. If it's outside of the popup, then return focus inside the popup. Or just trap the blur event if it would move outside.

Comment: @Martin: I've just edited my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I ended up with the following solution:

When the window is opened, I save the tabindexes for all elements not in the popup window inside jQuery.data and I set the focus to the first element of the window.

Then, for all those elements, I set the tabindex to -1 which prevents them from being accessed with the tab key.

When the window is closed, I restore all tabindexes to their previous values.

Comment: I don't get this. When you use `tabindex="-1"`, isn't the element focusable using `tab`?

Comment: No, when tabindex="-1", the element is not focusable.

Answer (score 1):

There is. You basically need to listen for when the tab key is pressed, so that you can respond accordingly. Using jQuery, here's the general structure:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which ===9){ //it's the tab key!
        //do whatever you want here.

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You put your custom code where I commented `do whatever you want here`, and finish up by preventing the default action (such as jumping focus to a hidden control) with `e.preventDefault`;

Comment: It won't work, tabkey still has to work, but only on the popup div.

Comment: Right, that's why you "do whatever you want here". So you can check which control currently has focus, and then call "focus()" on the control you want to move to.

Answer (score 1):

You could always look into removing the default actions of the `tab` key, there is a small tutorial on how to do this [here](http://dev.opera.com/forums/topic/169876).

However, that is for the `enter` and `tab` key, but if you also look [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.aspx), you will see that the `tab` key is key number 9. So if we alter the code to just remove the default actions of the `tab` key your line would be something similar to

```
    if ( key == 9 ) { }
```

rather than

```
    if ( key == 3 || key == 9 || key == 13 ) { }
```

**EDIT**

Okay, since now you've stated you don't want to prevent the default action of the `tab` key, but you still wish to stop that key from focusing on elements below the modal window.

The only thing I can think of now is, checking to see if the user is focused on your last field [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534971/in-javascript-find-if-a-checkbox-is-focused) / [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery) (you would link these to your last input/textarea/checkbox/radio). If so, you could do 1 of 2 things:

1) Use the above code and prevent the default action, thus, stopping the using from focusing on elements below the modal.

OR

2) Focus back on the first field in your modal window, with `first_field.focus();`

As far as I can see, by sticking with your requirements the second choice is the best option for you.

Comment: It won't work, tabkey still has to work, but only on the popup div.

Answer (score 0):

Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362/capturing-tab-key-in-text-box). Just prevent the user from pressing tab, or you'll have to loop through your fields and set tab indexes on them.

Comment: It won't work, tabkey still has to work, but only on the popup div.

Comment: I'd suggest hiding all the offending inputs with display:none while the window is up, browsers won't tab to inputs that it can't see

Answer (score 0):

I use a generic on focus event added to all input tags, when the event gets fired I determine the parent div's z-index if it is above a pre-determined threshold (9950 for example) then I allow the focus, if below I prevent focus.   To prevent focus I do this by finding a control within the proper div and calling .focus() on that item.

pseudo code below.

```
$('input').bind('focus', function() 
{ 
 if ($(this).parents('div:first').css('z-index') <  9950) 
 {
    //prevent focus here
    //usually by finding a suitable target and setting focus
   $('input:first', $('.myModalClass')).focus(); 
 }
});
```

ps. Also set the tabindex on the items so that the items within your "modal" window are right after each other in the tab index.   just makes things a little cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and created this tiny jQUeryUI plugin. Use it simply (in multiple places on a page if needed) and this will make TAB or shift+TAB iterate only inside of .someGroup wrapper.

$(".someGroup").tabGuard();

More in here and I hope it will help someone:

http://tomaszegiert.seowebsolutions.com.au/tabguard/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a better solution to your problem that doesn't involve disabling tab or having to track/disable other elements. It does require jQueryUI though.

```
<div id="modalBgCover">
    <div onfocus="$(this).next('div').find(':tabbable').last().focus();" tabindex="0"></div>
    <div id="modal">
        <input id="input1">
        <input id="input2">
    </div>
    <div onfocus="$(this).prev('div').find(':tabbable').first().focus();" tabindex="0"></div>
<div>
```

What this does is creates two tabbable (but without content, so not visible) divs which take and redirect focus.

Tabbing off the last input and into the bottom div will throw focus back to the first tabbable element inside the modal, and likewise shift+tabbing to the top div will throw focus back to the bottom input in the modal.

The modalBgCover overlays the page with a semitransparent layer, preventing clicks from getting through.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented mini-framework based on gather knowledge including answers in this post.

It uses JQuery UI.

Improvements are welcome.

Here is framework object:

```
var TabLim = {};

TabLim.activate = function(el) {
    TabLim.deactivate();

    TabLim._el = el;

    $(window).on('keydown', TabLim._handleTab);

    return TabLim;
};

TabLim.deactivate = function() {
    TabLim._el = null;

    // detach old focus events
    TabLim._detachFocusHandlers();

    TabLim._els = null;
    TabLim._currEl = null;

    $(window).off('keydown', TabLim._handleTab);

    return TabLim;
};

TabLim.setFocus = function(prev) {
    // detach old focus events
    TabLim._detachFocusHandlers();

    // scan for new tabbable elements
    var tabbables = TabLim._el.find(':tabbable');
    TabLim._els = [];

    // wrap elements in jquery
    for ( var i = 0; i < tabbables.length; i++) {
        var el = $(tabbables[i]);
        // set focus listener on each element
        el.on('focusin', TabLim._focusHandler);
        TabLim._els.push(el);
    }

    // determine the index of focused element so we will know who is
    // next/previous to be focused
    var currIdx = 0;
    for ( var i = 0; i < TabLim._els.length; i++) {
        var el = TabLim._els[i];

        // if focus is set already on some element
        if (TabLim._currEl) {
            if (TabLim._currEl === el[0]) {
                currIdx = i;

                prev ? currIdx-- : currIdx++;
                break;
            }

        } else {
            // focus is not set yet.
            // let's set it by attribute "autofocus".
            if (el.attr('autofocus') !== undefined) {
                currIdx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (currIdx < 0) {
        currIdx += TabLim._els.length;
    }
    if (TabLim._els.length) {
        TabLim._els[Math.abs(currIdx % TabLim._els.length)].focus();
    }

    return TabLim;
};

TabLim._handleTab = function(e) {
    if (e.which === 9) {
        e.preventDefault();

        TabLim.setFocus(e.shiftKey);
    }
};

TabLim._focusHandler = function(e) {
    TabLim._currEl = e.currentTarget;
};

TabLim._detachFocusHandlers = function() {
    if (TabLim._els) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < TabLim._els.length; i++) {
            TabLim._els[i].off('focusin', TabLim._focusHandler);
        }
    }
};
```

How to use it:

1) to activate to limit focus on specific div

```
TabLim.activate($('.yourDic')).setFocus();
```

2) to deactivate

```
TabLim.deactivate();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open your modal popup window if your trying to just get the focus on the first input when they initially press the "tab" key then a very simple solution would be to put the focus on the first input in your modal popup window then simply apply a .blur() to that same input. Then when you hit "tab" it will begin the focus on that form.

```
$("#modalTestInput").focus();
$("#modalTestInput").blur();
```

If you're trying to remove any ability to focus on the inputs behind the modal popup window then your solution to apply a `tabindex = "-1"` to the inputs outside of your modal popup is definitely the way to go.

Just thought you may be interested in a simpler solution.