# How can I check if my Element ID has focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have the following div that gets focus after a certain condition is met:

```
<div id="myID" tabindex="-1" >Some Text</div>
```

I want to create a handler that checks whether or not that div has focus, and when it evaluates to true/focus is on the div, do something (in the example below, print a console log):

```
if (document.getElementById('#myID').hasFocus()) {
            $(document).keydown(function(event) {
                if (event.which === 40) {
                    console.log('keydown pressed')
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm getting an error message in the console that says:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasFocus' of null

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Maybe the way I'm passing the div Id?

Comment: see thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate (the other topic asks an entirely different question), but today we can use the `matches()` method.

`var el = document.getElementById('myElement'); el.matches(':focus'); // If it has focus, it will return true.`

Answer (score 328):

Compare [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) with the element you want to check for focus. If they are the same, the element is focused; otherwise, it isn't.

```
// dummy element
var dummyEl = document.getElementById('myID');

// check for focus
var isFocused = (document.activeElement === dummyEl);
```

[`hasFocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus) is part of the `document`; there's no such method for DOM elements.

Also, `document.getElementById` doesn't use a `#` at the beginning of `myID`. Change this:

```
var dummyEl = document.getElementById('#myID');
```

to this:

```
var dummyEl = document.getElementById('myID');
```

If you'd like to use a CSS query instead you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)).

Comment: Why not just `document.activeElement.id=='myID'`?

Comment: @Meisner `document.activeElement` might be `null`.

Comment: Native JS `inputEl.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {if (e.target === document.activeElement) {e.preventDefault()}})}`. For react, don't use `onWheel` because it's passive. Use a ref and apply to `inputRef.current` in `componentDidMount`

Comment: Note that this may fail if the element is within an `iframe`, because `document.activeElement` will be the iframe, not the focused element inside it - see [Find focused element in document with many iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420219/find-focused-element-in-document-with-many-iframes)

Comment: `dummyEl.contains(document.activeElement)` will tell you whether `dummyEl` or any of its children have the focus.

Answer (score 28):

Use `document.activeElement`

Should work.

P.S `getElementById("myID")` not `getElementById("#myID")`

Comment: Also can use `document.querySelector("#myID")` instead

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use jquery `$("..").is(":focus")`.

You can take a look at this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus)

Answer (score 11):

This is a block element, in order for it to be able to receive focus, you need to add `tabindex` attribute to it, as in

```
<div id="myID" tabindex="1"></div>
```

Tabindex will allow this element to receive focus. Use `tabindex="-1"` (or indeed, just get rid of the attribute alltogether) to disallow this behaviour.

And then you can simply

```
if ($("#myID").is(":focus")) {...}
```

Or use the

```
$(document.activeElement)
```

As been suggested previously.

Comment: Also point out the typo in `getElementById`.

Comment: Thank you. I had already assigned a tabindex of -1. The $(document.activeElement) method works, but it's not specific to the  div that I'm checking for focus ('myID'). It triggers the if statement when ANY div has focus, not just the one I'm concerned with ('myID')

Comment: The jQuery method doesn't work at all

Comment: @KunalOjha yes, it should fire whenever there's an active element, it's your job to check if it's the one you need. So, you'd do if ($(document.activeElement).is('#myID')) {...} Also, when you set tabindex to -1, it `disables` the focus event on that particular element, you need to set it to 1 or any other number.

Comment: Still doesn't work :/

Comment: You should almost never be using positive numbers with `tabindex`. It should either be `0` or `-1`. See here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

Answer (score -5):

Write below code in script and also add jQuery library

```
var getElement = document.getElementById('myID');

if (document.activeElement === getElement) {
        $(document).keydown(function(event) {
            if (event.which === 40) {
                console.log('keydown pressed')
            }
        });
    }
```

Thank you...