# How to distinguish between onClick and onFocus events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, onfocus

I'm listening to the `onFocus` and to `onClick` events on the same input-element. The `onFocus` should **always set** a boolean to `true` and the `onClick` event handler should **toggle** this boolean.

But on a *click* both events are fired with the `onFocus` at first, so the boolean is being set to `true` first and then toggled by the `onClick`. How can I change this behaviour?

I tried to use `stopPropagation` inside the `onClick` event handler. Also setting a `isClicked` flag did not help. (Probably because both events are fired at the same time) (see JSFiddle)

```
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let isOpen = false

input.onclick = () => {
    isOpen = !isOpen
}

input.onfocus = () => {
    isOpen = true
}

input.onblur = () => {
    isOpen = false
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/coh29gwe/7/

At the first *click* on the input the `isOpen` flag should be **true** but is **false**.

Comment: Prevent default can be used, if nothing else, then for `isDefaultPrevented`

Comment: The design is perhaps flawed. Since you're also setting the Boolean to false when losing the focus, what's the point of toggling when clicked? Just tab off the element to toggle. Or have a separate control that toggles the Boolean when the input has focus.

Comment: @Akxe I tried this and there are 2 different events fired. `defaultPrevented` is still set to false in the onClick handler.

Answer (score 0):

there are some confuse when you are setting isOpen variable.
I think you should use `hasFocus` property of this `element` to indicate the opening state [Get focus state of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430561/how-can-i-check-if-my-element-id-has-focus)

or you can validate the value of `isOpen` in `onClick()` before you set it

```
if (isOpen == false){
    isOpen = true;
}
```

Because both of `onFocus` and `onClick` are fired when you perform a click thus you only need to set `isOpen` to true when `onClick` is called without `onFocus` (via script other some way that we don't know)

Comment: Thank you, there is indeed a mistake from me with the isClicked. Using hasFocus makes more sense here. I have an updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/zeu8nv5g/2/
Only Issue is this case: First focus, you need 2 Clicks to toggle.
But I think I can live with this solution.

Comment: I saw your code, and this is a coding mistake that you have set hasFocus to false. The onFocus() is called only 1 when you click 2 times because it has already focus in the second time thus has Focus isn't called again. You can take a look in here to see the change of element state http://jsfiddle.net/yojs6b4z/1/

Comment: ah you ment the `document.hasFocus()`, this always will be true, because the onFocus is set first.

Comment: and the **toggle** of the `isOpen` is the important part in my idea :-) which is missing in your code

Comment: yeah, i am understanding your idea know. Sorry for my not related answer before. http://jsfiddle.net/9hx21b6a/2/ i have updated my code, when onClick is called, it will reset the state of hasFocus and process base on the state. I know it not clean and may not work well in some case, please tell me the better answer if you found it.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem. It will allow only one update at one time.

```
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let isOpen = false

let updated = false;
function updateOpenedStatus(newStatus) {
    if (!updated) {
        isOpen = newStatus;
        updated = true;
        setTimeout(() => updated = false, 0);
    }
}

input.onclick = () => {
    updateOpenedStatus(!isOpen);
}

input.onfocus = () => {
    updateOpenedStatus(true);
}

input.onblur = () => {
    updateOpenedStatus(false);
}
```

However, as it seems you might want to change the behaviour altogether, as this [aria navigation-menu](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-links.html) and this handles events differently from your implementation.

Comment: This basicaly works. Allthough I need to set the timeout to 150 for Firefox or Edge. And it might depend on the operating system. But the approach is good.

Comment: @WayneJohn Well, that is too bad, this number could change at any point...