# Angular 7 how to check if any element has focus

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm looking to trigger a dialog function on keyup as long as no input is focused.
I have searched around and I have yet to find a solution.

I have tried document.hasFocus() but that didn't work. The function triggered regardless.

Any ideas?

```
      @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.router.url.includes('cart') || this.router.url.includes('rack') || document.hasFocus()) {
      console.log(document.activeElement);
      return;
    }
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = true;
    const input = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if (this.search === '' && /[a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(input)) {
      this.search = event.key;
      dialogConfig.data = this.search;
      const dialogRef = this.dialogService.openDialog(SearchBarComponent, dialogConfig);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
        data => this.search = ''
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430561/how-can-i-check-if-my-element-id-has-focus Let me know if worked for you

Comment: Bit unclear, some code would help maybe? In general, you’d do a hostbinding to listen to focus and then check your inclusions and exclusions by looming at the event target.

Comment: I want the dialog to pop up if the client does not click any inputs. Updated code to what I tried

Comment: @JoseVicente That didn't work, as that is checking for one specific input, whereas I want to see  if  ANY input was focused

Comment: Just check the event target and see if the node type is an input..?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just need to check if the activeElement is the body.

```
document.activeElement === document.body
```